# Fish food on Pesach

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven

In the Hidabrot this week they had the following statement:

[image]
This means Fish food since it is disgusting for humans to eat it does not need to be Kosher for Pesach…
I did a search on Otzer Hachochma to see what the source is for this and if this is a universally accepted opinion, I found According to (Reb Avraham, the son of Reb Shlomo Zalman Aurbach) says in פתחי אברהם 218 that even if there is an automatic feeder and the fish food is sold to a goy, you are getting Hanaah from chometz on Pesach. Rabbi Shammi Gross rules in a similar fashion.
I find it understandable why it would be assur on Pesach to have Hanaah. Can anyone explain please the understanding of the Hidabrot and why it would be allowed? There is still a problem of Hanaah from Chometz on Pesach!
Although this is related but not the same question: [What can I feed my fish over Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/what-can-i-feed-my-fish-over-pesach)

Answer (score 1):

I would have assumed it refers to something that is so disgusting that a [dog wouldn't eat it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56292/regarding-chametz-what-is-considered-not-fit-to-be-eaten-by-a-dog)

Comment: Agree, and a dog will eat a lot of things namely human excrement since it's relevant to the discussion otherwise I would just say a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

The שו"ע in או"ח תמב and other places in הלכות פסח brings down a מחלוקת about whether or not there is ביטול ברוב of mixtures from before פסח. I don't know if that's applicable in your case. Also, I'm not sure if they mean that it doesn't need to be kosher for passover, it may just not need to a הכשר, but you need to make sure it's not made from the five grains. In תמב סעיף א the מחבר paskens that as long as a תערובת is not ראוי למאכל אדם then it is fine. The question is if your fish food is חמץ נוקשה or not...?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%91 דבר שנתערב בו חמץ ואינו מאכל אדם כלל או שאינו מאכל כל אדם, כגון התריאק"ה וכיוצא בו - אף על פי שמותר לקיימו, אסור לאכלו עד אחר הפסח. ואף על פי שאין בו מן החמץ אלא כל שהוא, הרי זה אסור לאכול.

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%91#%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%9E%D7%91 ומ"מ בהנאה מותר כשנעשה התערובות קודם פסח